# '80s movie where a guy falls in love with a girl, then finds out she's a ghost

Tags: story-identification, movie, ghost

So I remember the movie with a guy being in love with, or liking, this girl. And then toward the end, she comes by, riding on the back of a convertible with some friends, looking to be dressed for prom, and 1950s music is playing, and he realizes she is a ghost. The guy looks so sad and then she drives off.

I cannot think of it or find it anywhere and it is driving me nuts!!! Please help. I'm pretty sure it was an '80s movie.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you watch this?

Comment: @DavidW - It's not clear from the description whether Krissy actually _saw_ the film in the '80s, or saw it more recently and just _thinks_ it was released in the '80s. I always like to clarify that, because I've seen cases where the OP's estimate of when something was released was years or even decades off the mark.

Comment: This actually sounds a lot like scenes that were dropped from American Graffiti

Answer (score 9):

Could this be [Susie Q](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susie_Q_(film)) (1996)? The final scene is very much as you describe, with the female lead in her prom dress being picked up in a 1950s car while the male lead watches.

> The film tells the story of a teenager dying with her boyfriend (Bentley Mitchum) on her way to their Winter Formal back in the mid-1950s and coming back to her old house 40 years later in order to help her parents avoid being kicked out of their trailer park home. Later, Zach (Whalin) moves into Susie's (Johnson) old house, but he is the only one who is able to see Susie.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Are you Afraid of the Dark episode like this.
The girl can't rest because her boyfriend never picks her up.
(he dies on the way to get her)
and this guy and his friend summon him (and do all sorts of Scooby-like newspaper searches)  at one point they are trying to resurrect him and are out on a river in a rowboat.
The girl is in casual clothing till the end when the dead guy shows up to "take her to the dance."

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you find which episode (number/name) this is?  That would greatly improve your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Was it Maxie (1985) I asked a similar question on another site and someone found it for me, so I can't take the credit here lol

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to specify the ways in which _Maxie_ matches the film described in the question. For example, does it have a scene toward the end where the girl is shown in a convertible with some friends, with 1950s music playing?