# Old romantic horror movie about a guy that fell in love with a girl and later found out she's a ghost

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, ghost

I watched this movie when I was very young and I can't remember the name of the movie. The movie could be from the 80s or 90s.

I only remember parts of the movie. I kinda remember a nerdy looking guy (possibly wearing glasses) who wasn't popular with the girls, and he finally got himself a pretty girlfriend, and he was driving an old car with a convertible soft roof top.

At the end of the movie, the guy and his girlfriend were inside the car and they were surrounded by a horde of zombies / ghosts attacking them. The ghosts were about to tear off the car's convertible roof, and the guy lit up a lighter of some sort at last, and all the ghosts vanished along with his girlfriend, then he finally realised she was also a ghost. The movie ended with him driving away in his car.

Please help, many thanks.

Comment: Sounds similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263108/80s-movie-where-a-guy-falls-in-love-with-a-girl-then-finds-out-shes-a-ghost but it has no accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

Is this ***[The Midnight Hour](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089593/)*** (1985)...?

The film takes place in the fictional town of Pitchford Cove, Massachusetts, on Halloween.

The protagonist, Phil Grenville, is a shy, a bespectacled high schooler who hangs out with four of his cooler classmates: Melissa, Mary, Mitch and Vinnie. He wants to ask Mary out, but she only has eyes for another guy.

After school, Phil's friends rope him into accompanying them while they sneak into the local museum to 'borrow' some old witchcraft-related artefacts, in preparation for a Halloween party due to take place at Melissa's house later that day. They unwittingly unleash a curse on the town when they break the seal on a 300-year-old scroll they found and recite the incantation on it.

> [image: Image of Mary, Vinnie, Phil, Melissa and Mitch, from "The Midnight Hour" (1985).]
>
> <sub>*The Midnight Hour* (1985)</sub>

Unbeknownst to them, the dead soon begin rising from their graves in the town cemetery, and some vampires and werewolves are loosed from Hell as well. Even when these creatures start roaming through town, they're not immediately recognised for what they are, due to the Halloween costumes many people are wearing.

While driving through town in his convertible, Phil meets a girl named Sandy, who's wearing a 1950s cheerleader's uniform. They immediately hit it off and grow closer as the night wears on. It's made obvious to the viewer that she's one of the undead, and she clearly knows it too, but Phil is none the wiser, as she looks and (mostly) acts like a normal person.

> [image: Image of Phil and Sandy, from "The Midnight Hour" (1985).]
>
> <sub>*The Midnight Hour* (1985)</sub>

By the climax of the film, Phil and Sandy figure out what's going on with the curse, and that in order to lift it, they they need to go to the cemetery and reseal the scroll with some candle wax. While there, they run into Phil's car to take shelter from a horde of undead -- who begin tearing through the car's roof -- and light a candle to melt some wax and reseal the scroll, after which there's a flash of light, and Sandy disappears along with the other undead.

> [image: Image of Phil's car being swarmed by the undead, from "The Midnight Hour" (1985).]
>
> <sub>*The Midnight Hour* (1985)</sub>

Phil then gets out of the car and sees the gravestone of Sandra Matthews, which states that she lived from 1942 to 1959. Finally realising what she was all along, he gets back into the car and drives off, listening to "[Baby I'm Yours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_I%27m_Yours_(Barbara_Lewis_song))" by Barbara Lewis on the radio.

You can view the relevant scene at around the 1:27:34 mark in the video below.

Comment: _Star Trek_ fans may wish to note that a pre-_TNG_ LeVar Burton plays the role of Vinnie in this film.